# Gradle error while importing library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have many problem with import module in android studio.

The first time when i tried to import module , gradle said : `target sdk not found.`

Then i installed target sdk , gradle said `target platform-tools not found`. And these errors not solving with installing sdk and platform-tools.

I have these errors while try to import sherlockactionbar and many else library.

```
gradle version : 2.8
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

build.gradle of my app:

```css
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "a.x.e.h.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':mylibrary')
    compile project(':actionbarsherlock')
    compile project(':actionbarsherlock-fest')
    compile project(':actionbarsherlock-i18n')
}
```

error when i added dependency module:

```html
Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 17.0.0
<a href="install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 17.0.0 and sync project</a>
```

Comment: Try to make a new module and check if the problem exists also. If this step is ok then I think the problem starts from the module that you want to import

Comment: @thanassis i tried to make and import new module (empty module for test) and i saw no error and worked well but when t try import else modules i give error that i said

Comment: Try to post your build.gradle , and the error received by gradle

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti added on first post

Comment: Check if you have the buildToolsVersion "20.0.0" in sdkmanage. I suggest you using the last 23.0.2.
Also check your module because the 17.0.0 doesn't exist.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti can you guide me how to do this??? Thanks a lot

Comment: Check the answer below.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti after do your answer i give new error : Gradle DSL method not found : 'android()'

Comment: You are using the android block in the top-level build.gradle file

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes i undrestand problem now gradle said that library need sdk 15 . Now i downloading that sdk . I hope this problem solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are using a build tool not existing in your installation.

- Open your SDK Manager and download the latest Build Tools (23.0.2).
- Update your build.gradle files (in your app and in your modules).

To do it change this line:

```
 buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
```

with

```
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. i going to do your answer and then say result here

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Project Structure and put the correct Path to the Android SDK.

[image]

Comment: i checked this and i saw no problem

Answer (score 0):

```html
Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 17.0.0
<a href="install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 17.0.0 and sync project</a>
```

I've solved the same problem with simply clicking on link above ( Install Build Tools 17.0.0 and sync project), Android Studio automatically downloaded Build Tools revision 17.0.0 and all now is working correctly.